# WPF DocumentViewer show document as byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

This might be a silly question, but I was wondering if it's possible to display a document in WPF's DocumentViewer control from a byte array.

If not, could someone provide an example of how the control is normally used to display a document? I can't seem to find a decent example.

Answer (score 0):

It is about arranging different UIElements:

```
        FixedDocument fixedDocument = new FixedDocument();
        DocumentViewer dv = new DocumentViewer() { Document = fixedDocument };
        this.Content = dv;

        var page1 = new FixedPage() { Width = 600, Height = 800 };
        PageContent page1Content = new PageContent() { Child = page1 };
        var sp = new StackPanel();
        sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock
        {
            Text = "Title",
            FontSize = 30,
            Margin = new Thickness(100, 50, 0, 70)
        }); 
        sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock
        {
            Text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog...",
            FontSize = 15,
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 10)
        }); 

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 150;
        rect.Height = 150; 
        rect.Fill = Brushes.Black;
        sp.Children.Add(new Rectangle
        {
            Width = 150,
            Height = 150,
            Fill = Brushes.Black
        }); 
        page1.Children.Add(sp);
        fixedDocument.Pages.Add(page1Content);
```